# Column/Character in a single line limitations with Writer class

Tags: java, string, file-writing

For the last few hours, I've been messing around with a text editor application I made. This editor is supposed to take input in a chapter-content structure and then write those inputs into a JSON file. The current code I use works fine until I try to put thousands of words into it. The problem is since this app is meant for novel writing/archiving, it is very important to be able to store those thousands of words.

The Writer class, which I use in this way:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(JFC.getSelectedFile() + ".json");
Writer fw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
fw.write(json);
```

with the json variable being the serialized JSON I made with GSON this way:

```
ArrayList<Chapters> allChapters = new ArrayList<>();

Gson gsonpretty = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gsonpretty.toJson(allChapters);
```

This code works fine for shorter texts as I said earlier, but longer texts cut off after about  24000 characters into the line. This is because the .toJson() method inserts all these long lines into one long column. Pretty printing the JSON helps a bit since the JSON notations are separated into their own lines but it will ultimately fail when it gets to writing the long content.

Is there any way to replace the "\n"s in the current text into actual newlines in the resulting JSON file? Keep in mind that writing a .json file works the same way as writing a .txt file.

Comment: What do you mean with "one long column". Multiline strings aren't supported by json. You can store escaped new lines that are handled ny your text editor

Comment: @peterulb I use column and characters kind of interchangeably here, my bad. Columns are the length of a text in a line in this case. So what I mean by "one long column" is one line of text full of characters with no true newlines. I actually made a test JSON file by hand beforehand and multiline strings seem to work fine, it automatically detects the true newlines in the file. My java text editor could only store newlines as "\n", not true newlines, so it will still stretch into one long column.

Answer (score 0):

After fidgeting for a bit, I found the way to fix my problem.
Since the text from the ContentArea is stored in a String ArrayList, the separators are stored using `\n`. The way to negate this is by simply replacing `\n` with `System.lineSeparator()` on the String serialized JSON like so:

```
String json = gsonpretty.toJson(ArrayList);
json = json.replace("\\n", System.lineSeparator());
```

This allows the written file to write true newlines, which negates the lines' column limitation. After trying to read it with my JSON deserializer, it works perfectly. In theory, an exceedingly long line of text could still throw an error, but I think that is unlikely to happen.